# Swift/Foundation NotificationCenter equivalent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a Swift/Foundation [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) equivalent in vanilla JS.

---

Here's a short explanation on what NotificationCenter is:

With NotificationCenter, you're able to post a notification and other objects can subscribe to that notification. When the notification gets sent, a function gets invoked in the classes that subscribed. Optionally, you can also send custom user info.

Subscribing to a notification looks like this:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(fooPosted),
    name: Notification.Name("foo"),
    object: nil
)
```

Posting a notification looks like this:

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.post(
    name: Notification.Name("foo"),
    object: nil,
    userInfo: ["bar": 42]
)
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @zelite "I'm looking for a Swift/Foundation NotificationCenter equivalent in vanilla JS."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming client-side javascript, you can use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to implement a basic pub/sub workflow:

```js
window.addEventListener("message", e => {
  console.log('got the message', e.data)  
});

window.addEventListener("message", e => {
  console.log('me too', e.data)  
});

n = 0
function test() {
  window.postMessage('hello' + (++n))
}
```

```html
<button onclick='test()'>test</button>
```

Alternatively, there are [custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent).